# Flagging a close question, declined due to wrong reason to flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged a question for very low quality, [this question in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027384/in-fluttter-zawgyi-font-incorrect-in-textfield), however, my flag was declined.

[image]

Obviously, since it was declined the question itself was found to be off-topic and closed. My question is sometimes I'm not the best at finding exactly what to flag a question as. I believed very low quality was fine but in the situation perhaps not. When flagging a question but unsure of exactly what to flag it as what is the best thing to flag it as? I'd like to avoid being declined as much as possible, more so when the question is in need of intervention.

Comment: "very low quality" means "rubbish" or "gibberish" that can't even be fixed by an edit. The linked question doesn't fall under that category. It is currently unclear due to missing information, but not "gibberish".

Comment: @Tom Can you give be an example of something that can't be fixed by an edit? That scope seems way too broad.

Comment: avoid flagging as "very low quality" if the question's content does not need direct deletion by a moderator, and if it can and should be voted to close by users.

Comment: @Script47 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34937233/revisions

Comment: @Tom fair enough, thanks for that.